# python-pkg-resources configuration errors

Tags: dpkg

I tryed to install python-setuptools in my debian distro.
I didn't install it successfully and now this is the error:
I translate some things in english..

```
debarm:~# apt-get update    
...(italian raws)   
ok

debarm:~# apt-get upgrade  
...(italian raws)  
2 half-installed  
Continue? y  
Configuration python-pkg-resources (0.6.14-4)...  
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>  
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>  
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]  
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback  
Could not import runpy module  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 320, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 299, in main  
    options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)  
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 217, in compile  
    pipe.send(fn)  
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 180, in py_compile  
    stdin.write(filename + '\n')  
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe  
dpkg: error while processing python-pkg-resources (--configure):  
Sub-process returned an error code (1)  

python-pkg-resources isn't configured.  
configured to not write apport reports  
configured to not write apport reports  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
python-pkg-resources  
python-setuptools  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  

debarm:~#
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.
Regards
Nick